# ASP.NET MVC RC returns wrong path for Url.Content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**UPDATE** this issue does not exist in the release bits of ASP.NET MVC

I have an ASP.NET MVC RC app which runs fine under the debugger running from http://localhost:9002/  But when I publish it to http://localhost/Zot/ the calls to Url.Content are returning incorrect values.

I have script tags like

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/util.js") %>" ...
```

In the published site this produces:

```
<script src="Zot/Scripts/util.js" ...
```

Instead of

```
<script src="/Zot/Scripts/util.js" ...
```

or

```
<script src="Scripts/util.js" ...
```

I have stylesheet tags like:

```
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" runat="server" ...
```

That produce the right thing:

```
<link href="Content/Site.css" ...
```

Any suggestions on why Url.Content is failing.  I clearly can't put a `runat="server"` on the `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to use Rob Conery's [Script Registration helper](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-script-registration-helper/):

```
public static string RegisterJS(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, string scriptLib) {
  //get the directory where the scripts are
  string scriptRoot = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Scripts");
  string scriptFormat="<script src=\"{0}/{1}\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\r\n";
  return string.Format(scriptFormat,scriptRoot,scriptLib);
}
```

Usage:

```
<%= Html.RegisterJS("myscriptFile.js") %>
```

As you can see in the example, this uses VirtualPathUtility to resolve the url of the Scripts directory. This should also help to bypass the problem of tag soup.

Comment: Rob, please also note Levi's response, as apparently this was a bug that was fixed in RC2.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This should have been fixed in RC2.  If you are using RC2 and are still seeing this problem, please file a bug at http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx.