# Root route breaking paths

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm in the process of deploying an ASP.NET MVC app to IIS 6, but am running into an issue with the root path.

In Global.asax, I have the root path mapped:

```
routes.MapRoute("Root", "", 
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

When I navigate to http://servername:70/test2/, the app displays the right page, but the stylesheet and JavaScript files are not loading. Looking at the source, the paths are showing like this:

```
<script src="test2/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="test2/Content/stylesheets/app.css" />
```

Which makes the browser look for

> http://servername:70/test2/test2/Content/stylesheets/app.css

When I go directly to a controller (http://servername:70/test2/Dashboard.aspx), the paths are correct:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/stylesheets/app.css" />
```

This is also occurring with any links generated with ActionLink. The stylesheet and script paths are being generated with Url.Content:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/stylesheets/app.css") %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612584/asp-net-mvc-returns-wrong-path-for-url-content/612741#612741) similar to this which uses Rob Conery's [Script Registration Helper](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-script-registration-helper/). I'll copy the answer in here for you, and add an example HtmlHelper for stylesheets.

```
public static string RegisterJS(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, string scriptLib) {
  //get the directory where the scripts are
  string scriptRoot = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Scripts");
  string scriptFormat="<script src=\"{0}/{1}\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\r\n";
  return string.Format(scriptFormat,scriptRoot,scriptLib);
}

public static string RegisterCSS(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, string styleLink, string rel) {
  //get the directory where the css is
  string stylesheetRoot = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/Stylesheets");
  string styleFormat="<link type='text/css' href='{0}/{1}' rel='{1}' />\r\n";
  return string.Format(styleFormat, stylesheetRoot, styleLink, rel);
}
```

Usage:

```
<%= Html.RegisterJS("myscriptFile.js") %>
<%= Html.RegisterCSS("app.css") %>
```

Hope this helps.

**Also**, I note that there was another response on that question by [Levi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59641/levi):

> This should have been fixed in RC2. If you are using RC2 and are still seeing this problem, please file a bug at http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx.

If this is your preferred answer, the please upvote Levi's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612584/asp-net-mvc-returns-wrong-path-for-url-content/612741#618214).

Answer (score 0):

Or, use the Url.Content ...

`<link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`